# Issues with doctrine build in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, jobeet

I am getting stuck with this Symfony command after following the Jobeet tutorial on their site. After running the build model command, here's what I get:

$ php symfony doctrine:build --model

> > doctrine  generating model classes
> >     file+     /private/var/folders/yX/yXtbVXwPHcCUpfC-n06OAU+++TI/-Tmp-/doctrine_schema_56533.yml

No yml schema found in `/private/var/folders/yX/yXtbVXwPHcCUpfC-n06OAU+++TI/-Tmp-/doctrine_schema_56533.yml`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, on OS X developing with NetBeans' Symphony support.

Comment: This was theoretically fixed, but I'm still having the issue running "fixed" code: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/7272

Answer (score 0):

What's then full path to your schema.yml? Looks like it might be in the wrong place.

I encountered a couple of issues in the jobeet tutorial and found it helpful to compare my file contents/paths to the tag for the relevant day at http://svn.jobeet.org/doctrine/tags/

Comment: My schema.yml is in config/doctrine/schema.yml.

Comment: thats correct - all i can suggest really is compare to whats in the jobeet svn repo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that all your schema code is YAML compliant?
Maybe you can share the content of your current schema.yml with us.